Lower bound for maximum matching size related to degrees of vertices.
I was given the following problem.
The vertices in a graph $G$ have degrees $d_1\leq \cdots \leq d_n$. Prove that
\begin{align*}
 \alpha'(G)\geq \underset{0\leq k\leq n-1}{\mathrm{max}}\lbrace\mathrm{min}\lbrace d_{k+1}, \lfloor{\frac{n-k}{2}}\rfloor\rbrace\rbrace.
\end{align*}
I don't know where to begin, so could anyone give me a hint on this problem?

. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Do you have any thoughts/attempts on how to approach this on your end? What happens if you try induction?
